# No spaces in synced folder path?

Tags: google-drive-api

How can I switch the synced directory on Windows to something other than 'Google Drive'?

Even though I'm on Windows I live in the command line and it is a pain to have embedded spaces in a directory.

Comment: this question is not really about the Drive SDK

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino Can you point me to another forum then?

Comment: @jaywgraves see below :)

Answer (score 6):

Jay please use the "google-drive-sdk" tag - and Stack Overflow in general - for developer questions.

If you require assistance on Google Drive please check our support page first: https://support.google.com/drive/?hl=en

If you still have consumer questions regarding Google Drive please use our Drive product help group: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!forum/drive